# Leaflet: How can i show layer only inside a polygon

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, shapes

Actually i'm working with Leaflet but when i add a leaftlet.webglheatmap layer it uses the entire screen.

I need to show only the data (colour) inside a geoJson polygon, instead of all the map:

I talked with the webglheatmap developer but he told me to create a new shape with webgl, but that is not an option in this minute

I tried Leaflet.Snogylop too, but it just draw a shape outside my map and with some colours it doesnt do the effect.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code and it would the best to have a working demo.

Comment: It would be more useful, if you add a demo instead of creating a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you need to show map layer only within Polygon. Unfortunately it's not straight forward with leaflet. I stumbled with same issue an year ago and I ended up using **[Leaflet Snogylop](https://github.com/ebrelsford/Leaflet.snogylop)** Plugin. Simply put by the author:

> Leaflet.snogylop is a Leaflet plugin that inverts polygons.

Basically you define a polygon where you want to show the map, this plugin will invert that polygon so that rest of map is covered while your desired area is transparent.

**Inverted Polygon**
[image]

**Inversted MultiPolygon**
[image]

**Usage**
Include the lib in your page after leaflet, then use it by simply defining the `invert` option to true

```js
L.geoJson(data, {
    invert: true
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Sure! it would help, but the sad part is i only need to cut the temperature layer, that is the hard part :(

Comment: You can define the temprature layer and then invert it? Sorry if I am not understanding you clearly. You want the area between the black and white lines to be visible/colored or the white structure itself?